# Match unless "escape" character is present

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm making a bot which gives full links for wikilinks like [[Foo]] given on IRC. What I want to do is to have '[[foo]]', 'before [[foo]], '[[foo]] after' and 'before [[foo]] after' match, but not '`[[foo]]', 'before `[[foo]]', etc., '`' being a sort of "escape" character in the program. So far I got

```
/[^`]\[\[(.+)\]\]/
```

However, that doesn't match "[[foo]]". If I add a ? after the negated character class, it defeats its purpose and all the backticked links still match.

How could I do this?

P.S. I want to have a *single* regex.

Comment: Does a backtick escape a backtick?

Comment: Sadly, it seems that Ruby doesn't support negative lookbehinds, which would make this trivial...

Comment: You should use backticks to make it clear what strings you are talking about. Your quotation/tick is inconsistent, and I suspect it is not balanced.

Comment: @sawa, you're right. I started writing this on my computer and then finished it off on my iPod, where I couldn't find the backtick character.

Comment: iPod? You mean iPad? Or, iPod touch? Either way, technology.

Comment: @sawa, iPod touch, as if it mattered. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the beginning of the line as an alternative to "a character that is not `` ` ``":

```
/(?:[^`]|^)\[\[(.+)\]\]/.
```

Comment: Oh, I had imagined that but I didn't think it would work. Yet another demonstration of regular expressions' raw awesomeness. Thanks!