# Match unless “escape” character is present; must work inline and back-to-back

Tags: javascript, regex

This question is very similar to [Match unless "escape" character is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323103/match-unless-escape-character-is-present), however the approved solution doesn't work in all cases.

In my scenario, I'm using javascript and want to capture contents in [square brackets], unless they escape it with \[slash].

[A RegexPal is here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gims&regex=%28?:%5B%5E%5C%5C%5D%7C%5E%29%5C%5B%28%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D*%29%5C%5D&input=This%20is%20a%20%5Bblock%5D,%20but%20as%20you%20can%20see%20it%20is%20trying%20to%20capture%20the%20preceeding%20character.%20%0A%0AYou%20can%20%5C%5Bescape%5D%20a%20block,%20but%20this%20creates%20%5C%5Bproblems%5D%20with%20%5Bblocks%5D%20that%20are%20%5Bstacked%5D%5Bback%5D%5Bto%5D%5Bback%5D.).

RegEx

```
(?:[^\\]|^)\[([^\]]*)\]
```

Sample to test against to see issue:

```
This is a [block], but as you can see it is trying to capture the preceeding character. 

You can \[escape] a block, but this creates \[problems] with [blocks] that are [stacked][back][to][back].
```

Comment: You could match both and filter afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript's regex engine doesn't support lookbehind..

You can use this workaround

```
(?:\s|^|\])\[(\w+)(?=\])
```

Group 1 captures your required data within `[]`

[Demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5Cs%7C%5E%7C%5C%5D%29%5C%5B%28%5Cw%2B%29%28%3F%3D%5C%5D%29&input=%5Bblock%5DThis%20is%20a%20%5Bblock%5D%2C%20but%20as%20you%20can%20see%20it%20is%20trying%20to%20capture%20the%20preceeding%20character.%20%0A%0AYou%20can%20%5C%5Bescape%5D%20a%20block%2C%20but%20this%20creates%20%5C%5Bproblems%5D%20with%20%5Bblocks%5D%20that%20are%20%5Bstacked%5D%5Bback%5D%5Bto%5D%5Bback%5D.)

Comment: @Anthony oops..there was some minor mistake in the regex..i.e it was not able to match if `[]` was at the beginning of string..i have corrected the error..check out the edit